# KDE on Windows won't download/install

Tags: windows-7, installation, kde, checksum

No matter which mirror I use, I get this error.  I've tried a few times over the last several weeks.

```
Download failed
---------------------------
The download of ftp://kde.mirrors.tds.net/pub/kde/stable/4.5.4/win32/libopensp-vc100-1.5.2-bin.tar.bz2 failed with error: archive downloaded from ftp://kde.mirrors.tds.net/pub/kde/stable/4.5.4/win32/libopensp-vc100-1.5.2-bin.tar.bz2 checksum error
---------------------------
Retry   Ignore   Cancel
```

Should I just ignore this and let it continue?

Update: I ran as administrator, changed the install directory to C:\KDE, and ignored this error, and it seemed to install, but then gave me a different error, same file:

```
Error
---------------------------
Internal Error - File C:/Temp/KDE/libopensp-vc100-1.5.2-bin.tar.bz2 does not exist
---------------------------
Cancel
```

But now programs seem to work!  Should I just ignore this error?  It lists`libopensp` as "a library for a SGML parser algorithm".

Comment: I've just used kdewin installer (latest version as of 26 Feb) to download that file with no problem. Also, the ftp site in your post is up and working so I would guess the problem is local to you and your PC. Has it ever worked?

Comment: Also, where are you saving/installing to?

Comment: The file downloads, but it gets a checksum error.  Installation to `C:\Program Files (x86)\KDE`, download path `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp\KDE`, download server `winkde.org`, release `stable 4.5.4`.  It has not ever worked.

Comment: Try changing your download and installation paths to a new directory such as C:\KDE, somewhere outside of the Windows or User directories.

Comment: I tried running as administrator and using `C:\Program Files\KDE` instead, but same error.  I tried moving the directories to C:\ and still the same error, but only with that particular file.

Comment: Sorry, but that's the only bit of advice I have.

Comment: I also struggle to install because the installer cannot load mirror list from sourceforge. :-/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried downloading the latest version of the KDE Win32 installer?  It could be that the files online have changed and your installer is looking for the older versions with different checksums.

Comment: Although saying that I just tried the latest KDE installer and it couldn't even get the list of mirrors from sourceforge.

Comment: Yes, I'm using the latest version.